# Problem with cookies ASP.NET / React.js - not saving

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, asp.net-core

I've problem with setting token with react app. Im getting "refresh-token" from API response

```
    private void SetTokenCookie(string token)
    {
        var cookieOptions = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8),
            Path = "/auth/refresh-token"
        };
        Response.Cookies.Append("refreshToken", token, cookieOptions);
    }
```

There is no problem in Postman. I received from response in Headers -> Set-Cookie - refreshToken=3CTqZ6GQNT%2FxsmbUjFJQnkdkSd1utwtPtmxBtpawbZXCXwLR1HqvM3u3ZeJ6rRoidOSUTDJ17B0tku2PD7qeVw%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 14 Dec 2021 23:57:32 GMT; path=/auth/refresh-token; secure
But when im using browser, this cookie is not saving.

[image]

Comment: `This token is not appear in Chrome browser only on my PC` if possible, you can try to uninstall and reinstall your Chrome browser, or reset the browser settings, then check if it can help fix the issue.

Comment: Reinstalling is not working :/ still im facing with same problem. Right now its not working also in debug and other browser. This just works on Postman App.